# How to validate Toaster of Angular Js using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am new for testing  Angular js app with Protractor.
I have a submit button on click of it, Toaster Message gets pop up on window.

Button to submit is below.

```html
   <button title="Add the Expense Claim" ng-show="addExpDetailsShow" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addExpenseDetails()">Add</button>
```

Toaster div is as below

```html
<div class="toast-top-right" id="toast-container"><div style="" class="toast toast-error"><button class="toast-close-button">×</button><div class="toast-message">Select Expense Type.<br>Amount should be between 0.10 to 100000000.</div></div></div>
```

Now i need to validate whether the toaster is displayed or not and need to validate toaster message. I am using jasmine to write my test case. By googling  i wrote below code .

```
it('adding expense', function(){

    element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-collapse']/ul[1]/li[2]/a")).click();
    element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='main-container']/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/button[1]")).click();    
    element(by.css('[ng-click="addExpenseDetails()"]')).click();
    toast = $$('.toast toast-error');
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000);
    expect(toast.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('some value');
     expect(toast.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Validating toaster is similar to validating any other elements in protractor. However the challenge is to validate within the time frame it appears and disappears. To verify its details, try waiting for its appearance and then validate it. Here's how -

```
it('adding expense', function(){
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    element(by.css('[ng-click="addExpenseDetails()"]')).click()
    //Verify toast after click event returns promise
    .then(function(){
        toast = $('.toast toast-error');
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(toast), 20000) //wait until toast is displayed
        .then(function(){
            expect(toast.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('some value');
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When i run your code  i m getting an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: I clear above error by replacing : "var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;" with  var EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;. but i am getting new error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDisplayed' of undefined.

Comment: @Naveen Are you sure the toast element locator is proper. I suggest changing the toast locator to - `toast = $('.toast toast-error');` . $$ is used to find array of elements of a parent, [check this](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$$). Let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
it('adding expense', function(){
    var EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;
    element(by.css('[ng-click="addExpenseDetails()"]')).click()
    //Verify toast after click event returns promise
    .then(function(){
        toast = $('.toast-message');
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(toast), 20000) //wait until toast is displayed
        .then(function(){
            expect(toast.getText()).toEqual('some value');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Use getText () instead of getAttribute ()

Comment: A little explanation would have been useful too.

Comment: getText() will only get the inner text of an element. To get the value, you need to use getAttribute().